# Show x,y of div and update values as div moves

Tags: jquery, html, dom, animation

I have a div moving in a loop (with jquery). I am able to write the x,y position to the page; however, only the initial values get written to the page. Is there a way to update the values as the div moves?

```
var sun = $j(".sun");
var position = sun.position();
$j(".sun").circulate({
  speed: 3600,
  width: Wwidth,
  height: Wwidth,
  loop: true,
  zIndexValues: [1000, 1000, 1000, 1000]
});
console.log('x: ' + position.left + ' y: ' + position.top);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you modify the circulate plugin you are using so it makes a callback every time it changes the position of the sun. Or you can just put your reading part in a setInterval statement:

```
setInterval(function (){
   var sun = $j(".sun");
   var position = sun.position();
   console.log('x: ' + position.left + ' y: ' + position.top);
},1000); // This code will be runned each 1000 ms, so you can modify it..
```

Comment: Np, glad to help. Mark it as answered =)